# get local time with boost

Tags: c++, boost, time

I didn't find this in documentation: how to get local time (better formatted) with boost?

Comment: I mean that I wanna format output data.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [posix_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#ptime_from_clock) to construct a time object from the system clock.

For example, this would output the current system time as an ISO-format string:

```
namespace pt = boost::posix_time;
pt::to_iso_string(pt::second_clock::local_time());
```

For formatting alternatives, see the “Conversion to String” section of the above-linked reference and the [Date Time Input/Output](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html) reference. Alternatively, you can build your own output string using the accessor functions. For example, to get a US-style date:

```
namespace pt = boost::posix_time;
pt::ptime now = pt::second_clock::local_time();
std::stringstream ss;
ss << static_cast<int>(now.date().month()) << "/" << now.date().day()
    << "/" << now.date().year();
std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
```

Note the month is cast to `int` so it will display as digits. The default output facet will display it as the three-letter month abbreviation (“Mar” for March).

Comment: Note: The required include for this is: ``boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp`` (I stumbled on this earlier)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will be of any help, but boost docs have some [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html) of formatting dates.

Plus, I think that [this article](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/date_time/local_time.html) describes some basics, which are worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Date Time Input/Output APIs:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.io_objects

Comment: There is a lot of samples for the converting input data, but not about getting that data from system information.